# RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the module requires API v12.0

Tags: api, pyqt4, python-sip

So I am facing this error:

> **RuntimeError**: the sip module implements API v11.0 to v11.2 but the module requires API v12.0

I believe this has been answered a few times on the web for different versions of sip and PyQt4, however, I could not find any set answer for two definite things:

- Everyone asks to remove all versions of sip and PyQt4 before a fresh installation.  Can someone help with a set command to do that (remove all sip and PyQt4 versions iteratively)?
- I want to run `PyQt4 import QtGui` specifically.  Can someone tell me the right PyQt4 and sip version to do that?

***OS Details***

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

***Python Version***

```
2.7.12
```

Thanks for helping,

Adarsh

Comment: Nobody can help you unless you explain *exactly* what you have already done. What did you install (give all the specific versions), and how did you install them?

Comment: I tried the following things- 
sudo -H pip install SIP and sudo -H pip install PyQt4
which gave me the following error - 
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SIP/PyQt4 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for SIP/PyQt4"
Hence, I further tried - sudo -H pip3 install SIP
which worked and installed some module somewhere.
Then I dowloaded and installed from the tar files - 
I installed SIP version - sip-4.19 and
I installed PyQt4 version - PyQt4_gpl_x11-4.12
This is as far as I can remember.
Please let me know if you need any further info.
Thanks
Adarsh

Comment: Also weirdly enough there seems to be a new folder with distribution packages from python3 in my system now at -
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
(I use python 2.7 as earlier mentioned)